# Getting results from subthread to main thread in other way than signals

Tags: python, qt, threadpool, worker, qrunnable

It possible to obtain results from the Worker object (QRunnable subclass) in other way than signals? The reason for this is that I don't think (please correct me if I'm wrong) that signals should be used for sending large amounts of data e.g. like dictionaries with COM MailItem objects from outlook which I processed asynchronously with pythoncom.CoInitialize() or big pd.DataFrames. As I understand, the data transfer through signals/slots is slow.
Is there a safe way to return the worker object after QThreadpool finished running so I could retrieve the results attached to it?

Comment: It's unclear or too broad. You mean a worker thread sends data frequently to the main thread? Or it sends a large data only once?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. Let's say that I want ot do it once. I have a long lasting task performed in the QRunnable but in return I want to have a number of objects let's say classes that have methods to do sth in outlook and have MailItems attached to them. The question had a more genral purpose about getting some heavy results from the subthread without signals.

Comment: If you edit the question for clearness and specificity, I'll answer the question.